# Identifying text that does NOT contain a character

Tags: sql-server, regex, powershell

How can I find mentions of the ADB database that are -NOT- followed by `.dbo`?

I thought that using `[^d]` would find strings that do -NOT- have a `d`, but it does not appear to work.

```
PS C:\> 'FROM [ADB].[dbo].[ATABLE] T' | Select-String -Pattern '\[*ADB\]*\.\[*[^d]'

FROM [ADB].[dbo].[ATABLE] T

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.1
```

Comment: The optional `[` ends up matching the condition "not a `d`". Move both into a negative lookahead instead: `'\[*ADB\]*\.(?!\[*d)'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thank you for this. In my case, I moved the optional RIGHT SQUARE BRACKED and PERIOD into the capture group. `'\[*ADB(?!\]*\.\[*d)'`

Answer (score 0):

Since `Select-String` has switch `-NotMatch`, the straight-forward solution is to create a regex that matches `[ADB].[dbo]` and then invert the results with said switch. Also, the `[regex]` type accelerator offers access to `escape()` that'll make short work of adding backslashes. Like so,

```
$tests = 'FROM [ADB].[dbo].[ATABLE] T', 'FROM [ADB].[sys].[ATABLE] T', 'FROM [ADB].[DBO].[ATABLE] T'  

$pattern = [regex]::escape('[ADB].[dbo].')
foreach($t in $tests) {
  select-string -NotMatch -pattern $pattern -InputObject $t
}

# output
FROM [ADB].[sys].[ATABLE] T
```

Note that the output is per default not case sensitive. If that is required, use the appropriate switch like so,

```
foreach($t in $tests) {
  select-string -NotMatch -pattern $pattern -InputObject $t -casesensitive
}
# output
FROM [ADB].[sys].[ATABLE] T
FROM [ADB].[DBO].[ATABLE] T
```

Comment: I suspect OP wants to match all variations, eg. `ADB.[dbo].`, `[ADB].[dbo]`, `[ADB].dbo` etc.